# Wordpress theme update - how to not lose customisations on the parent theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hoping someone experienced could share his knowledge and expertise on this. I was trying to find a good explanation on how to not lose customisations from my theme after an update, but I still cannot find a guide, without telling me to have a child theme **before** the customisations. However, I read them too late, and when hired freelancers, they have done the customisations on the parent theme files.

I am now running on a child theme, but, unfortunately, few of my customisations have been done before the move and they are still on the parent theme.

My thinking is can I:

1. "extract" locally my customisations,
2. update the theme,
3. copy back the customisations to the functions.php? (parent or child this time)

The extracting, can I do it: by comparing the code in e.g. Sourcetree: my customised parent functions.php with the original file I downloaded at the very start? (attached screenshot)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMsQE.jpg)

When copying back the customisations - can I copy it to the child functions.php instead of the parent file?

What about customisations that have been done on different files other than functions.php and style.css - how can I find which other files have been altered in the parent files or know which one I should manually alter?

Will customisations on plugin files stay the same and not break the plugins after the update?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one slightly crude/basic idea:

Create a repo/directory, add a copy of the original parent theme to it (at the same version of the one you modified (the whole theme, unmodified original copy)).

Now dump your modified parent theme in to the same directory. Agree to replace any existing files.

Now view the changes between each file via a GIT client such as [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) or [TowerApp](https://www.git-tower.com/mac)

This will let you know what differences there are across **all** files.

**Functions.php**:
Now you can see which changes there are betweeen the original parent and your modified versions, you can copy function.php changes to your `child-theme/functions.php` file yes.